# Eclipse "Makefile Project with Existing Code" can't view nor open source files

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse 2020-12 release under Linux. I installed C/C++ support.

I have a project that is configured by `CMake`, using `Unix Makefiles` generator.
Note that the source files are not in a sub-folder of the folder containing `CMakeLists.txt` and `Makefile`:

- sde/

  - code/

    - cpp and header files
  - build/

    - CMakeLists.txt and generated Makefile

From Eclipse, I do File New -> Makefile Project with Existing Code, and then I pickup the folder where my `Makefile` was generated by `CMake` (sde/build).

Eclipse opens the project and I can build it from here. But the problem is that the "Project Explorer" tab of Eclipse does not list my source and header files. I see here the `CMakeLists.txt` and `MakeFile`, and if I open `Makefile` I see it has valid absolute paths to my source code files (.cpp and .h), however they are not present in the "Project Explorer". Is there any trick to have them be displayed?

Note: I see the same issue with every Eclipse release I could test (see comments)

Comment: Eclipse Helios is 17 releases behind and more than 10 years old. There is a separate [Stack Exchange for retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Consider using a recent [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) instead of your old Eclipse Helios

Comment: @howlger: I'm not root, so I must deal with the version installed. I kepler version is also available, I'll try it. But I doubt it will work better...I suspect this is more a configuration problem, maybe due to the fact that my sources are in a different folder.

Comment: @howlger: I confirm kepler release has exactly the same behaviour.

Comment: You do not need to be root. Download Eclipse as `*.tar.gz` file, unzip and run it. And there is at least one person who is root and who you can talk to.

Comment: @howlger: Just got Eclipse 2020-12. It has exactly the same problem. Files are not part of Project Explorer.

Comment: Recent versions of Eclipse CDT actually come with CMake support. Don't configure your project as a Makefile project in that case. Alternatively, for older CDT versions, I recommend to use the [cmake4eclipse plugin](https://github.com/15knots/cmake4eclipse).

Comment: Does a _Linked Folder_ work (to map the directory containing the source files into the project)? Right-click the project and choose _New > Folder_, in the _New Folder_ dialog click _Advanced_ and choose _Link to alternate location (Linked Folder)_.

Comment: @howlger: THis works but then loads the whole code folder, while I would expect to nly find here files used by imported Makefile.

Comment: I see. If I understand you correctly, the problem is that the files listed in the Makefile should show up in the _Project Explorer_ under _Includes_, but they do not, right? This seems to be an Eclipse CDT or C/C++ specific problem where I don't know a solution (I'm not a CDT expert and not a C/C++ developer).